# 1-2-3 star level awards algorithm

Tags: algorithm

What I am trying to do is to have individual star counts per level based on player performance.  (1-2-3 star awards.)  This will be based on what region the player reaches.  I know how to award the stars but keeping track of it all is throwing me problems.  First lets say a player plays level 2 and receives 1 star for their performance.  Then at a later time, s/he returns to the level and gets a 2 star. I would like the star count for that specific scene to update to two stars, while only adding 1 star ( The one extra s/he got this time) to the totalStarCount.

My initial plan was to have variables:

```
OldStarCount
NewStarCount
TotalStarCount
```

Then when a player reaches say region1, and is awarded one star, then NewStarCount would be set to one, then

```
TotalStarCount = TotalStarCount + (NewStarCount - OldStarCount);
Then update OldStarCount = NewStarCount;
Set NewStarCount = 0;
Move On to next Scene;
```

Am I approaching this the correct way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Depending on how many levels you have, you could just keep a list of all star counts, and compute `TotalStarCount = sum(StarCounts)` on the fly. This has the advantage of not requiring you to track previous and new star counts for each level.

Comment: Hmm so if a player scores lower then his or her previous attempt, then do nothing, and if they score higher, update the score and continue?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that. `StartCounts[level_id] = max(StartCount[level_id], new_result)`, or something like that.

Comment: Just a side comment, but in most languages its considered standard to have your variable names start with a lowercase letter, FWIW.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was just in a rush typing, usually its like   totalStarCount... etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this

```
int result = 0;
int totalStars = 0;
int[] starCounts = new int[NumberOfRegions};
...
currentRegion = 42;

result = play(currentRegion);
if(result > starCounts[currentRegion]){
    totalStars += result - starCounts[currentRegion];
    starCounts[currentRegion] = result;
}
```

This is just an example of what you could do.  There are obvious scalability issues with this (what happens when you want to add new regions, etc), but you get the gist.

Comment: This is good, but it will always have only 3 regions so I dont need to worry about having anymore than that.

Comment: "I don't need to worry about having anymore than that".  Famous last words :)

Comment: Lol, I know that sounds dumb for game programming but this is just a simple game that is marked by regions, 1 2 and 3 stars. I will not be awarding any higher star counts, thus dont need any higher region counts =)